# Could Saturn's Rings be removed?

Tags: internal-consistency

Superman was hitting the Kryptonite a little hard last night and thought it would be funny to fly opposite Saturn's Orbit.  He didn't fly fast enough to affect the planet's orbit, but like a whirlpool affect in a kiddy pool, he disrupted and then reversed the orbit of the debris field forming Saturn's Rings.

If he got the rings going fast enough in the opposite direction, could he cause them to fly out of orbit and "clean the planet up"? (His words, not mine)

Comment: For those voting as off-topic - where exactly would I ask something like this?  I'm exploring a mini-disaster wherein Saturn lost its rings.  The Astronomy board would be waaaaay over my head especially when I'm just vetting ideas.

Comment: Okay, *someone* who casts a close vote has to comment (I'm not casting a vote, I'm just saying this to whoever does). I definitely think this can have applications to worldbuilding, though it may be worded in a way where that is not apparent.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli I didn't cast a downvote, and won't. I think it's fine question. But to answer your comment's question: "Not every question has a home on a SE site." I ran into this myself with a question concerning naming standards with variables several months back.

Comment: Alllso: if they go in the opposite direction enough where they are no longer falling forward (what orbiting is) they'd fall down, and into Saturn. Does your world's Superman consider this "cleaned up?"

Comment: @SteveMangiameli, if you have the time and would like a deeper understanding of orbital mechanics on an intuitive level, I'd recommend Kerbal Space Program.  For all its strangeness, it gets two body systems correct enough for non-astrophysicist users.  It's a great place to explore how to get stuff in orbit and back out of orbit.

Comment: If the orbit could be stopped and the rings burned up or settled on Saturn, that would definitely be cleaned up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing would happen, at all. Saturn's rings aren't suspended in media like water or air, so there's nothing Superman would drag against to influence their orbits. Unless Superman now has the mass of a small planet, I haven't been keeping up with the comics.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the media part.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of direction if he increased the velocity of the ring debris above [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) they would stop orbiting Saturn and fly off into new orbits around the Sun.  Their new orbits would then likely interact (or collide) with other objects in the solar system causing mayhem and destruction.

Superman, when he sobered up, would likely have many chances to heroically redeem himself by saving earth from a number of extinction level asteroid impacts.

Comment: I'm not much of a physicist, but wouldn't increasing their velocity in "co-orbit" cause them to pinch in on the planet?  Or would the pinching happen just before reversal?  Or not at all?

Comment: Speeding up causes deorbit. Slowing down will cause them to crash. Also Saturn's rings are made of small objects. May be couple of meters in diameter and mostly made of ice. A lot of debris will hit earth but I don't think it will be enough to make any extinction event.

Comment: "Speeding up causes deorbit". No. Speeding up raises the orbit, up until eventually escape velocity is reached and the debris end in heliocentric orbit. Slowing the debris down causes it to de-orbit and crash into Saturn.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work like you think. Think about a whirlpool versus a still pool: in a whirlpool the water pulls away from the center and moves to the edge of the pool. Saturn's rings are like a whirlpool already - by orbiting around the planet, the rings keep away from the center of the pool (the planet).

If he tries to reverse the orbit of the rings, he has to stop them and then get them moving in the opposite direction. But what happens when they're stopped? They fall into the planet. So the rings will disappear all right, but not by flying off into space.

Comment: But even if the orbital motion of the rings completely stopped, the ring particles would only fall toward nadir (point directly below, on Saturn) at escape velocity, which is what -- 20 km/s or something like that? There would be ample time for Superman to get them going again before they descend into Saturn's atmosphere, assuming that he simply realizes the error of his ways quickly. Of course, the ring system would look somewhat different afterwards, and a few people at various space agencies and observatories might scratch their heads in confusion, but the ring system would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

What whirlpool? Only pebbles he would affect are the ones he would collide with, and ones that collide with previous ones. Given that only about 3% of rings' volume is solid (rest is just an empty space) and that rings are rather thin (few meters), he would knock some rocks out of them, but would be really unlikely to affect any serious amount of matter.

Now, for the orbit. To make something fly out of it, you want to increase it's orbital speed. Value of it. Plane or direction doesn't matter. To reverse direction, you either need to stop rock and then accelerate it backwards -  it'll be falling down in the meantime, getting closer to planet - or you need apply force to the side, and make it to make a really narrow turnaround. Even then, you are risking hitting planet more than throwing particle away.